# mysql and phpMyAdmin databases do not match

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm starting to learn mySQL and PHP programming and I faced this problem. I create a database in phpMyAdmin and it doesn't show up in mySQL command line client with the request:
"SHOW databases". I tried it vice versa and phpMyAdmin doesn't find it. Although, I can connect via php script to databases created in mySQL command line client but not to the ones created by phpMyAdmin.

I connected both sides with the root user.

Can anyone explain me how all this thing works?

Comment: View your database using a web browser localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: Do you understand the difference between "table" and "database"?

Comment: @Richie, the cript I use in php is

`<?php
 require_once 'login.php';
 $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

 if(!$db_server) die("unable to connect to mysql: " . mysql_error());

 mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("unable to select database: " . mysql_error());
?>`

Is that what you mean?

The error I get is `"Unknown database 'store'"` meanwhile I have it in phpMyAdmin panel.

Comment: @Samurai8, Yes, I create databases not tables. I create both databases, in phpMyAdmin and mySQl command line, via sql commands.

Comment: Why do you require 'login.php' in your config file?

Comment: Is a file where a store some values. The content of this file is. `<?php
 $db_hostname = 'localhost';
 $db_database = 'databasetest';
 $db_username = 'username';
 $db_password = 'password';
?>`

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same mysql server with both clients? You could check the output of `SELECT @@hostname;`

Comment: @VMai, the result is the same in both sides.