# XAMPP MySQL and phpMyAdmin have different databases

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am new in XAMPP MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. The databases on these two platforms should be the same. However, similar to the problems shown in [MySQL and PHPMyAdmin matching problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25593781/mysql-and-phpmyadmin-databases-do-not-match),

I found that `SELECT @@hostname` have the same results on XAMPP MySQL and PHPMyAdmin. However, the result for running `SHOW databases` on XAMPP MySQL is

*
information_schema |
mysql   |
people  |
performance_schema  |
phpmyadmin  |
test
*

whereas the result for running `SHOW databases` on PHPMyAdmin is

*
information_schema |
test 
*

By the way, I am running XAMPP MySQL on Windows 10 PowerShell. Comments and ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you're connecting through phpMyAdmin, you're authenticating to MySQL as the anonymous user. Most MySQL installations come with an anonymous user which doesn't have many privileges at all, but can connect and see the databases you reference.

This could be because you're using a different username and password, or because the two methods are using a different connection type — to MySQL, a connection to over TCP/IP networking authenticates as a user with host "%" (or a specific IP address). A socket connection authenticates to the "localhost" host. Using host names of 127.0.0.1 (or any IP address/hostname) forces a TCP/IP connection; connecting to 'localhost' forces a socket connection.

So probably what's happening here is that you're using the phpMyAdmin default connection type of localhost and telling the command-line client to connect to 127.0.0.1, but you only have your user set for host '127.0.0.1' (or '%'). You can edit your phpMyAdmin configuration to tell it to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead, or duplicate the user@127.0.0.1 and give the new user the host 'localhost'. Either should get you in again if this is the cause.